# Nginx grant access to specific machines without the use of IP

Tags: nginx

I recently tried to block all ip instead of mine for access on the get-go, to my site. 
But turns out, my internet provider changes IP address so after, I can't use the same IP twice in a day. So, I would like to allow nginx allow access based on other alternatives, such as: browser agents.

I would like to know how I can achieve this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use browser agent.. this is neither unique nor unsusceptible to forging and just imagine you're using another browser some day. Use basic auth instead: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10

Answer (score 0):

You could also use port knocking with something like fwknop. It is great. Unless you or another one of your servers knock, it looks like a dead port and just times out.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fwknop-to-enable-single-packet-authentication-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Hiya, this link is probably great... but links go stale, so we prefer you to copy out the relevant portions into your answer so that the question always remains viable (for posterity) ;)